# BigQuery - Remove specific duplicate records

Tags: sql, duplicates, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table containing data as below:

```
date  hits_eventInfo_Category  hits_eventInfo_Action  session_id  user_id  hits_time  hits_eventInfo_Label

20151021  Air  Search  1445001  A232  1952  CurrentLocation
20151021  Air  Search  1445001  A232  1952  CurrentLocation
20151021  Air  Search  1445001  A232  1952  CurrentLocation
20151021  Air  Select  1445001  A232  7380  Vendor
20151021  Air  Select  1445001  A232  7380  Vendor
20151021  Air  Select  1445001  A232  7380  Vendor
```

As you can see there are a series of duplicate records. I would like to end up with **one of the duplicate records from each of the duplicate record sets**. For example:

```
date  hits_eventInfo_Category  hits_eventInfo_Action  session_id  user_id  hits_time  hits_eventInfo_Label

20151021  Air  Search  1445001  A232  1952  CurrentLocation
20151021  Air  Select  1445001  A232  7380  Vendor
```

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use a DISTINCT clause, or group your data.  These will aggregate the data returned into a single line for each unique entry.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [date], [hits_eventInfo_Category], [hits_eventInfo_Action], [session_id], [user_id], [hits_time], [hits_eventInfo_Label]
FROM [BigQuery]

--OR

SELECT [date], [hits_eventInfo_Category], [hits_eventInfo_Action], [session_id], [user_id], [hits_time], [hits_eventInfo_Label]
FROM [BigQuery]
GROUP BY [date], [hits_eventInfo_Category], [hits_eventInfo_Action], [session_id], [user_id], [hits_time], [hits_eventInfo_Label]
```

Note: This won't delete your duplicate data, it just won't be displayed in the results of your select statement.  If you would like the duplicate entries deleted permenantely, use @singhsac 's response utilizing window functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the duplicates. Keep one row, and delete the remaining from the duplicate group:

Try this (I've assumed table name and other fields)

```
;WITH rmvDuplicate
        AS (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [date],  [hits_eventInfo_Category],  [hits_eventInfo_Action],  [session_id],  [user_id],  [hits_time],  [hits_eventInfo_Label]
                                        ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) dup
            FROM    BigQuery_table)
    DELETE FROM rmvDuplicate
    WHERE   dup > 1
```

Comment: Partition over  all the columns that you think are repeating the value in the table.

Comment: not correct for bigquery which is append-only https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables?hl=en#deletingrows